# k-combinations in lexicographic order (using given algorithm)

Tags: c++, combinatorics

I already solved the problem, but it seems my code is too awkward, and with a different approach there could be a more elegant solution.
Notice that the general algorithm is described in the instructions:

**This is the problem description:**

> Given unsigned integers 0 ≤ k ≤ n, generate all the k-combinations of
>   the n objects, numbered 1, 2, ... , and n, using the following
>   algorithm:
>
> Starting with the combination 1, 2, ..., k, the next combination is
>   found by scanning the current combination from right to left so as to
>   locate the rightmost element that has not yet attained its maximum
>   value. This element is incremented by one, and all positions to its
>   right are reset to the lowest values possible.
>
> Each line contains a set of n and k which separated with at least one
>   space.
>
> For each case, the first line is a prompt as following: “case 1:”. The
>   next lines are all of the combinations. Notice that one line for one
>   combination and list the results in ascending order. You don’t have to
>   print any thing if the result is null. The last line of each case is
>   an empty line, even if the result is null.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int combination_find(std::vector<int> combination, int max_val);
void combination_inc(std::vector<int>& combination, const int& pos, const int& max_val);

int main()
{
    int round = 0;
    int n, k;
    while (std::cin >> n >> k)
    {
        //init
        std::vector<int> combination;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < k)
        {
            combination.push_back(++i);
        }
        std::cout << "case " << ++round << ": " << std::endl;
        while(1)
        {
            //writes (upon conditional so that the print of empty vectors doesn't mess up the text formatting0
            if (!combination.empty())
            {
                std::copy(combination.begin(), combination.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
                            std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            //check
            int pos = combination_find(combination, n);
            if (pos < 0) {break;}
            //increment
            combination_inc(combination, pos, n);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int combination_find(std::vector<int> combination, int max_val)
{
    if (combination.empty()) { return -1; }
    if (combination.back() != max_val)
    {
        return (combination.size() - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        combination.pop_back();
        return combination_find(combination, --max_val);
    }
}

void combination_inc(std::vector<int>& combination, const int& pos, const int& max_val)
{
    int val = combination[pos];
    for (unsigned i = pos; i < combination.size(); ++i)
    {
        combination[i] = ++val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`combination_find()` takes \$O(K^2)\$ time and space because of the pass by value. This is unnecessary overhead and can cause trouble when K is large. Instead we can easily find the position iteratively.

```
int combination_find(const std::vector<int> &combination, int max_val) {
  for (int i = combination.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i, --max_val) {
    if (combination[i] != max_val)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This also allows us to pass the vector by reference.

A few more minor points

- `combination_inc()` does not need `max_val` as a parameter
- The `push_back()`s in the beginning can be replaced with [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) in C++ 11
- Perhaps it is better to combine the `find` and `inc` into a single `next_combination` which returns true if the combination has been updated, similar to the behaviour of [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). The behaviour of `combination_inc` to require `pos` as an argument and modifying it through `main()` is strange to say the least.